# Failed to execute goal io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.2.0.Final:package (default) on project mongo-demo

Tags: java, maven, thorntail

I'm having issues with my Maven project. I am trying to use the command "mvn clean install" but I'm having no success. I have updated & cleaned the Maven project in the Eclipse IDE. I have also deleted the folder "repository" within the ".m2" directory. This creates the folder again but I keep getting the same error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

My pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <version.thorntail>2.2.0.Final</version.thorntail>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.thorntail}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: Tried it your pom.xml and it worked. My Maven Version: 3.5.2 Java: 1.8.0_181

Comment: This looks OK on the first sight. What is the JDK version you use?

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is the Maven version** (BTW which one are you using?)

When I run my **Thorntail** project using eclipse's embedded maven (**version 3.5.3** ) **it works**.

When I run it using my local maven (**version 3.6.0**) **I get the same error.**

**Solution**: use a compatible version of maven. ( **try 3.5.3** or **3.5.4**) **both work without issues with thorntail**.

If you want to configure a different eclipse maven version go to:

Eclipse -> preferences -> Maven -> installations

there you can add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem due to third-party dependencies in Thorntail 2.x, that are incompatible with latest Maven release. The new Thorntail version should be the 2.3.0.Final once released.

On GitHub, you can track the [status of the issue here](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/pull/1195)